# How to use string interpolation

Tags: ruby, string

I have the following question:

```
person = "John", building = "Big Tower"
```

I want to use Ruby's string interpolation to produce the following:

```
"My friend John owns the building Big Tower"
```

Is this the correct answer:

```
puts "My friend #{person} owns the building #{building}"
```

??

Comment: Can you not answer this question yourself in irb?

Comment: @FrederickCheung I wont be posting it if I could. Give some support to beginners please :)

Comment: I don't think anyone understands your question - there seem to be constraints you haven't mentioned or a definition of "correct" that isn't clear

Comment: Why you don't test yourself the statement **puts "My friend #{person} owns the building #{building}"** If it works before asking the question? The only error that you have in your code is in the variables' declaration, put a semicolon to separate them. Otherwise the first variable person is considered as an array of two element by the interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intended the variable assignment to be Ruby code, then it is wrong. It should be

```
person = "John"; building = "Big Tower"
```

or

```
person, building = "John", "Big Tower"
```

And for the question, yes, except that interpolation is a feature of Ruby, not Rails. Please be respectful to plain Ruby and its developers, and don't confuse it with Rails. Rails is only a framework built on top of Ruby. Rails is not the only use of Ruby.

Comment: really sorry. I found that I wrote it ROR instead of Ruby. 
Q1. Can I edit the title?
Q2. Please execute it on http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0
Why it does not give the required output?

Comment: Don't change the declaration. It is already declared like this, tell me how to change its string interpolation?

Change this >> puts "My friend #{person} owns the building #{building}"

Comment: You *have* to change the declaration because the declaration isn't valid Ruby. It will raise a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag In fact it's not a syntax error, it's a semantic error. Because by separating the two variables by a comma, will make the first one **person** as an array of two elements **["John", "Big Tower"]** you can test it yourself, and the second one will be a variable of string type "Big Tower".

Comment: @Amaynut: Ah, you're right, it's parallel assignment.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, there's no syntax error in your declaration. It's a **semantic error**, because when you declare two variables or more separated by comma and you assign them values at the same time, the ones before the last will be considered as arrays by ruby.

The following declaration:

```
person = "John", building = "Big Tower"
```

With the following statement:

```
puts  "person: #{person}", "building: #{building}"
```

Will output this:

```
person: ["John", "Big Tower"]
building: Big Tower
```

So, if by any constraint you cannot change your declaration to separate the two variables, the solution to your question would be to pick only the first element of your first variable like this:

```
puts "My friend #{person[0]} owns the building #{building}"
```

This will work. You can test it here http://ideone.com/ca2zw4

Answer (score 0):

Consider this output of of IRB or the TryRuby interpreter:

```
> a=1,b=2
=> [1, 2]
> a
=> [1, 2]
> b
=> 2
```

This shows that @sawa's answer is right, that the problem is not in your interpolation, but in your compound assignment. Ruby interprets that as:

```
a = 1,(b=2)
```

Your problem is that you need to swap it to `a,b=1,2` or, in your code,

```
person, building = "John", "Big Tower"
```

Please accept the answer by @sawa.

---

Alternatively, if you cannot change the initial, broken-code:

```
puts "My friend #{person.first} owns the building #{building}"
```

…or…

```
puts "My friend #{person.first} owns the building #{person.last}"
```

…or…

```
person = person.first # Fix the mistake
puts "My friend #{person} owns the building #{building}"
```

Comment: You guys are not understanding what I am trying to do.

Let me explain it once again. It is declared already, I cannot change the declaration in the code (some other codes are working on it that I am not allowed to change). The only this I can change is the last line: puts "My friend #{person} owns the building #{building}"

So the answer by @sawa is not correct.

Comment: @DeeJay': the declaration is *broken*. You *must* fix it. Period. It does not do what you think it does. It's that simple.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Man. How about its a question in a quiz and you have to solve it? Can you change the question? It compiles in Ruby(which means it is not broken), and I need to get the answer.

Comment: See the edit at the bottom of my answer, or the suggestion by @Amaynut, for how to modify only your interpolation to handle your 'odd' data.