# ruby expression for string interpolation

Tags: ruby, string, string-interpolation

name = "James Kirk", starship = "USS Enterprise"
Given the variables above, write a Ruby expression that uses string interpolation in order to produce: "The captain of the USS Enterprise is James Kirk"

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use string interpolation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472826/how-to-use-string-interpolation)

Comment: No I will not take your orders.

Comment: This sounds like a question from a learning Ruby course?

Comment: @maniacalrobot Yes, it is. and i have been doing a small mistake in answering it(use of puts statement).So,wanted to know if there is any other way of doing it.

Comment: @JGreenwell I've tried the code below
 name = "James Kirk", starship = "USS Enterprprise"
puts "The captain of the #{starship} is #{name}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So interpolation works like the following. You first need to have double quotes like using the ""'s. Then inside of those double quotes you just add the # and then the {} which contains the block of code that you want to run. So in this case you have 2 assignments:

```
 name = "James Kirk" 
 starship = "USS Enterprise"
```

Would result in you "interpolating" the variables in the string such as this:

```
what_you_want = "The captain of the #{starship} is #{name}"
```

Hope this helps! If not, please leave a comment and I'll elaborate.

Comment: your variable assignment is a syntax error should be: name, starship = "James Kirk", "USS Enterprise"

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out JGreenwell. I didn't think he would actually assign it like that, but some people might see it and actually incorrectly try to assign variables like that. I edited my answer for clarity.